# Design patterns for versioning steps across data/workflow pipelines?

Tags: version-control, data, workflows, pipelining

I'm sure this has been touched upon by a number of questions, but I'm struggling on drawing the boundaries between code, data and configuration versions when working with a large DAG (think airflow or Dagster).

There are a few things that change over time:

1. The source data (data always changes over time)
2. The code (code improvements, some logic changes)
3. The environment (updating dependencies)
4. The configuration (similar to code changes, but a configuration is more similar to an experiment than to a strict upgrade).

Each run of the DAG generates new assets.

My problem is: I am finding it hard to answer questions like

- "how did the config change affect asset `x`?"
- "are the changes to asset `y` due to the data changes or the code changes? can we run the new code against the old data? Can we run the new data vs the old code?"
- "can we hot swap asset `z` for the version from last week"

This is generating a very complicated mental model were all versions of the dag, present and past, and all their materialization reference each other.

[image]

Does anyone have guidance on how to manage this complexity?

#### EDIT: More thoughts

I guess the main challenge I have is tracking & referencing assets across dag runs.

It's all good to say "asset x depends on assets x1, x2, x3" but it's hard express cross-run dependencies in the pipelining tool itself.

DBT has this nice `{this}` variable that allows you to reference the current version of a table in the logic to update the table.

Comment: Perhaps a first simplification could be noticing that code and configuration are all just kinds of data